# SVG pictures are not displayed

Tags: html, laravel, svg, sass, laravel-blade

I am using images in svg format for the first time. and they aren't displayed my project. I tried with png and it works. I also tried changing the size, color etc.. Thank you!

Data file where the images and their title are stored (
I don't think that's the problem because when I replace the links with .jpg pictures, it works)

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Data{

    public static function getSkills()
    {
        return [
            // array data
            array("name" => "HTML5", "icon" => '/home/student/Bureau/Portfolio/public/images/skills/bootstrap.svg'),
            array("name" => "CSS3", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/css.svg' ),
            array("name" => "Sass", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "Bootstrap", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "JavaScript", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "MySQL", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "PHP", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "React JS", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "Redux", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "GitHub", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "Trello", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "VSCode", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
            array("name" => "Linux Ubuntu", "icon" => 'public/images/skills/html5.svg'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Data;

class SkillsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        return view('competences', [
            'competences' => Data::getSkills()
        ]);
    }
}
```

competences.blade.php

```
@include('layouts/navbar')
<div class="skills">
    <h1 class="skills-title text-center"> <span class="the-span "> Compétences </span></h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle text-center"> <span class="the-span "> •Les langages, outils et frameworks que j’utilise </span></h2>

      <ul class="skills-list text-center m-auto">
      @foreach ($competences as $competence)
          <li class="skills-list-skill" key="{{$competence['icon']}}">
            <embedy src="{{$competence['icon']}}" alt="" class="skills-list-skill-icon" />
            <p class="skills-list-skill-title">{{$competence['name']}}</p>
          </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
</div>



@include ('layouts/footer')
```

Scss file

```
// Variables
@import 'variables';
.skills {
    margin-bottom: 10em;
    margin: 3em 0 2em 1em;

    &-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        @media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
          width: 60%;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
          width: 70%;
        }
    &-skill {
        width: 7em;
        @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
          width: 5em;
        }
        background-color: $second-font-color;
        margin: 3em 3em 1em 0;
        min-height: 7em;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 1em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        font-size: .8em;
        text-align: center;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            img {
              color: $font-color;
            }
          }

          &:nth-child(even) {
            img {
             color: $second-font-color;
            }
          }
          &:hover {
            transition: .8s;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
          }

          &-icon {
            padding: 1em 2em;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            color : white;

          }
    }

    }

}
```

[image: FINAL RESULT]

Comment: Is `<embedy ...` a custom component or a typo?

Comment: Not really seeing how PHP is relevant here tbh. This sounds like a 100% frontend issue/question. You should rather post the generated HTML than the PHP source. Btw, the first URL (for HTML5) seems to be an absolute file system path instead of a URL.

Comment: Since you're using Laravel: the `/public/` folder should be the "DocumentRoot" of your web server and should _not_ appear in URLs. Use `/images/...` instead of `public/images/...`

Comment: @brombeer thanks! I replace my Urls but still doesn't work . I tried with <img> and <embed> in fact :) I just put the img tag back

Comment: `<img>` should work fine if you update the paths/use the correct paths to the svgs.

Comment: I put '/images/skills/html5.svg' everywhere and replace <embedy> with <img> but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Inspect the elements, make sure the URL is correct. Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see if the images get loaded but not displayed. Do the files exist? File permissions are ok?

Comment: in the browser's DevTools/Network tab, I get a 200 request starting with data:image/svg+xml... In the page elements, the images are finally there but I still don't see them on my website. it's like they went behind the red divs...? –

Comment: I updated my first post above with a screenshot so you can see the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `<embedy>` tag for, you can simply try load your svg icon with img tag

```
  <img src="{{$competence['icon']}}" alt="" class="skills-list-skill-icon" />
```

also you dont need to add complete address to getaddress method ,you can just add icon name and in code load with `asset`

```
 <img src="{{asset('/images/skills/'.$competence['icon'].')}}" alt="" class="skills-list-skill-icon" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I get an error : 'ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'icon' (T_STRING), expecting ')' (View: /home/student/Bureau/Portfolio/resources/views/competences.blade.php)'. I tried to remove some quotes '' but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry I had a mistake try this:<img src="{{asset('/images/skills/'.$competence['icon'])}}" alt="" class="skills-list-skill-icon" />   @LaureCHAPERT

Comment: @LaureCHAPERT  also remove full path from getSkills function and just add icon full name on it

Comment: Thank you, I have no more errors! in the browser's DevTools/Network tab, I get a 200 request starting with data:image/svg+xml... In the page elements, the images are finally there  but I still don't see them. it's like they went behind the red divs...?

Comment: I updated my first post above with a screenshot so you can see the final result –

Comment: @LaureCHAPERT  try remove img class first , if again it not visible add  z-index to img tag

Comment: Oh thank you very much! it was the img class! Too much padding I think! thank you very much and 'nice day!

Comment: your welcome you can do me a favor and accept my answer :) @LaureCHAPERT